# MySQL Foreign Key with Django

Tags: mysql, django

Im using MySQL with Django, and get an error when running syncdb after defining a Foreign Key.

```
class Contact(SalesforceModel):
    Account = models.ForeignKey(Account)

error:
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1075, 'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key')
```

MySQL cannot handle multiple auto_increment fields in a table. I'm thinking this can't be an uncommon problem though, and that there must be a way to make this work.

```
python manage.py sqlall reports

    CREATE TABLE 'Account' (
        'Id' integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        'Name' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    );

    CREATE TABLE 'Contact' (
        'Id' integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        'FirstName' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        'LastName' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        'Account_id' integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
    );

    ALTER TABLE 'Contact' ADD CONSTRAINT 'Account_id_refs_Id_2a366952' FOREIGN KEY ('Account_id') REFERENCES 'Account' ('Id');
    CREATE INDEX 'Contact_e5e91692' ON 'Contact' ('Account_id');
```

Comment: What's a SalesforceModel?

Comment: Can you post your entire model definition plus SalesfordeModel ?

Comment: What is the point of having 2 auto incrementing fields in this case? Can't you work around the problem completely by having only 1 auto incrementing field? I don't see how a foreign key is auto incrementing btw... it normally isn't.

Comment: The Account_id field is specified as Account = models.ForeignKey(Account) in models.py. Django appends '_id' to the name and adds the auto_increment property when I run syncdb. The added auto_increment is what is confusing MySQL.

Comment: I'm using the django-salesforce module, from salesforce.models import SalesforceModel.

Comment: There might be something going wrong with the field ("Account") shadowing the model ("Account") in the class statement's scope but then it would be a rather interesting bug. Just try to use "account" (lowercase) instead of "Account" as the field name and see if that solves the problem. If yes then it's one more good reason to follow pythonic naming conventions ;)

Comment: Interesting idea, I tried the lowercase account, but that didn't change anything. The problem is that django generates code that adds the auto_increment constraint when defining the foreign key, and mysql doesn't like more than one auto_increment field.